# close Google Chrome accidentally and variables in jupyter notebook are missed

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I accidentally closed Google Chrome while running jupyter notebook, and when I restart jupyter notebook again， the variables I got from my previous run are gone, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the variables are not saved when you close instances of Jupyter notebook. They are gone. The code is saved automatically every now and then (or manually when you do it yourself). But if that hasn't happened in a while, you'll need to rerun the code to re-generate the variables.